# if statement inside jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting those 2 vars from the DOM:

```
var get_category = $('#category').find('.current').attr('rel');                             
var get_subcategory = $('#subcategory').find('.current').attr('rel');
```

and I want here to find the classes in my DOM and show it

```
$('.filter-result').find('.'+get_category, '.'+get_subcategory ).show();
```

But I need to write it inside the `.find()` only if the variables are exist

Comment: only if which variable exists? Please elaborate

Comment: @zzzzBov: I assume he means `get_category` and/or `get_subcategory`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, you know what they say about people who assume things... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it answers your question:

```
var get_category = $('#category').find('.current').attr('rel');                             
var get_subcategory = $('#subcategory').find('.current').attr('rel');

var classes = [];

if (get_category) {
    classes.push('.' + get_category);
}

if (get_subcategory) {
    classes.push('.' + get_subcategory);
}

//if get_category or get_subcategory were found
if (classes.length) {
    $('.filter-result').find(classes.join('')).show();
}
```

Comment: No, it's not working right, are you sure you meant ('.get_category')? it doesn't look like that what suppose to be

Comment: i need to find the div with multiple classes for example: $('.filter-result').find('.category.sub');

Comment: @NelsonDenver those classes inside the **find** call, where do they come from? Do you mean that the element found in the rel attribute of the **#category** and **#subcategory** should have a class and the class of this element should be added to the **find** method?

Comment: I have this classes already in the DOM: http://i.imgur.com/XmsAIQ8.png I just created a button and when I click on that I want to find from my vars that I'm getting for example: find('.cat.sub').show();

Comment: So, it I understood right, you should change
`classes.push('.get_category');`
to
`classes.push('.' + get_category);`
(the same for the subcategory)

Comment: oh thanks, i also had to remove the comma here: classes.join(',')

Answer (score 0):

I do like Gabriels answer because it is very simple another option that works well and is extensible all you would have to do add another selector is add it to the selectors array. It is a little bit more advanced using javascripts filter and map array methods though.

```
var get_category = $('#category').find('.current').attr('rel');                             
var get_subcategory = $('#subcategory').find('.current').attr('rel');

var selectors = [get_category, get_subcategory];

var query = selectors.filter(function(elem) {
    if (elem) { return elem };
}).map(function(elem){ 
    return '.' + elem;
}).join(', ')

$('.filter-result').find(query).show();
```